# Does anything like Code Bubbles exist yet?

Tags: user-interface, debugging, ide

The [Code Bubbles](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/acb/codebubbles_site.htm) project was announced years ago, and I've wanted to try something like it ever since. Yet every now and then, when I think to myself, *So much time has passed; surely they've released an IDE using that bubbles concept by now!*, I hit up Google and see nothing but tantalizing mentions of the idea from 2010.

Is there anything *like* Code Bubbles that I can download and try out today?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the original code bubbles [for Java](http://www.cs.brown.edu/people/spr/codebubbles/) is still around.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, so it turns out there *is* something:

[Debugger Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/debuggercanvas). An add-on for Visual Studio, in fact!

Now I'm excited to try it out later.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Leo](http://leoeditor.com) - Literate Editor with Outlines. It is written in Python and has many of the features I think Code Bubbles aspires too but without the graphical view.

Think outlines, but with the ability to position related pieces of code close to each other or in any way that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2015, I've recently released [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension that supports working sets and function-based views of the code.